# How can I show only selected slides in a PPT slide show?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I have a large deck of over 150 slides containing several sections, each one with its "customs show list" of 5-10 slides.

When showing all sections to a customer, he shows me which specific points he wants discussed at the meeting.

How can I select section 1, 4, and 7, for example, from the initial slide show mode so only those sections displayed in continuous show?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

1. Going to Slide Show tab
2. Click on Custom Slide Show
3. Click on Custom Shows
4. Click NEW
5. Select which slide #'s to present,
6. Name the group as you see fit.

To present that group, just go back to Custom Slide Show and click the one you named.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the 'hide slide' option on powerpoint to do that. select all the slides you want to hide, rightclick, and hide slides.